# Laravel Route Middleware auth:admin not working for all Routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to pre check two different Route Groups by the auth:admin middleware. This works perfectly for the first Route Group inside but not for the second which is in an other Namespace.

My Routes file looks like this:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function(){

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function(){
        Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'team/{team_id}', 'namespace' => 'Team', 'as' => 'team.'], function(){
        Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
    });

});
```

If I'm not logged in and try to go to admin/dashboard, I'm redirected to login/admin. But if I try to go to team/1/dashboard it says Error 'Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object'. 
How can I get the auth:admin Middleware to work with my Team Routes too?

Answer (score 0):

create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#defining-middleware)

```
class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->permission == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->route('some.route'); // If user is not an admin.
    }
}
```

Register in `kernel.php`

`protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'is.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
];`

So your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'is.admin'], function () {
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function(){
        Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'team/{team_id}', 'namespace' => 'Team', 'as' => 'team.'], function(){
        Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check app/Http/Controllers/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file and
update the code for different guard use

// app/Http/Controllers/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($guard == "admin" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }
        if ($guard == "writer" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/writer');
        }
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```